# AngularJS processing input value

Tags: html, angularjs

When i start typing a name of student, like "M", the list of student needs to include only students, name of that are starting on letter "M" and so on rest of the word. But input value .length is undefined all the time.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('DataController', function() {
    this.students = arr;
    this.compare = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++) {
        if (this.text[i] == this.students.name[i]) {
          alert(this.text);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  var arr= [{
    name: 'Azurite',
    price: 2.95
  }, {
    name: 'Bloodstone',
    price: 5.95
  }, {
    name: 'Zircon',
    price: 3.95
  }];
}());
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <input class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" type="text" placeholder="Search people by name..." ng-model='text' ng-change='data.students.name'>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-sort">Sort by name</button>
      <button class="btn btn-sort">Sort by age</button>
      <button ng-click='data.click()' class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Main content-->
  <div class="main-table col-sm-8  col-md-7 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat='student in data.students' ng-show='data.compare()'>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="/img/cat.svg" alt="">
          </td>
          <td>{{student.name}}</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>sieg@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.text` isn't defined anywhere.  It *looks like* you have declared your controller like `DataController as data`, so your `ng-model` should be `data.text` rather than just `text`, but even that won't work, because `this` inside the function points to the function, not the controller....

Comment: Just use the filterFilter. That's what it's for. No need to write your own.

Comment: @Claies, it's defined in the ng-model attribute.

Comment: but that's the point, it's *definately not* set in the `ng-model`, the `ng-model` is pointing to a property on `$scope`.  Again, as I said, even changing to `data.text` instead of just `text` wouldn't work, since the function doesn't have access to the controller's properties.

Comment: also, you really should provide ***sane*** example data;  here you have an HTML document that is trying to iterate through `students`, but your sample data looks like `gems`?  half the properties in your code aren't present on your dataset.

Comment: @Claies please explain me how to solve this "since the function doesn't have access to the controller's properties"?

Comment: you have a controller, and inside the controller you have a function.  inside the function, `this` points to the function, not the controller.  adding properties to the controller won't make them visible inside the function.

Comment: Ooouch, and how do i avoid using functions inside controller?

Comment: in this case, there is already a `filter` feature built in to angular to do what you are trying to do.  However, you don't "avoid" using functions inside a controller, that's the wrong question.  The question should be, how do I avoid using `this`..,,

Comment: however, when attempting to recreate your example, I found other flaws as well.  your `ng-change` will never work, and using `ng-show` to call a function is a very bad practice.  I was going to make an attempt to show how to fix this code, but since it has so many issues, I definately recommend using the `filter` feature instead.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @Claies, thank you so much. I am new at angular, just ended codeschool course and thats all :) And yeah, they prefer this, rather then $scope. I don't know why.

Comment: using `Controller as` has some advantages over `$scope`, most notably testability, easier migrations to Angular 2, and better compatibility with ES6.  It does, however, require a bit more understanding about JavaScript Prototype Inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *angular way* to do this is to use the `filter` feature built in to angular.

first, the text box you want to type your search into:

```
<input class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" type="text" 
       placeholder="Search people by name..." ng-model='data.text'>
```

Note that this only needs an `ng-model` value.

Next, the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody ng-repeat='student in data.students | filter:data.text'>
```

Nothing is necessary at all in the controller.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aoR2ZkrgjCvhC60Ky0QA?p=preview